# how to pass a function from server component to client component nextjs 13 app dir

Tags: next.js, nodemailer

im trying to  make a function and whenever the user clicks on it, it sends an email with nodemailer.
But when i run the code i get this error

```
functions cannot be passed directly to client components unless you explicitly expose it by marking it with "use server".
```

i tried adding the use server but it still didnt work

```
    import React from 'react'
import Wholesignupcontainer from './wholesignupcontainer'

import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

function page(email) {

 async function g(){
"use server"
    let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: 'email',
          pass: 'password'
      }
    });
    let mailDetails = {
      from: 'okormorupraisecoding@gmail.com',
      to: 'okormorupraisecoding@gmail.com',
      subject: 'New signup',
      text: "email"
    };
    mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails)
  }
  
  
  
  return (
    <div>
        <Wholesignupcontainer g={g}/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default page
```

i read nextjs docs and they said the function has to be serialized in the server component and deserialized in the client component
but when i do that i get another error

```
referenceerror: nodemailer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not defined
```

but nodemailer is installed properly
pls help me
i dont know what else to do

This is my code

```
    import React from 'react'
import Wholesignupcontainer from './wholesignupcontainer'

import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';

function page(email) {

  function g(){
    let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: {
          user: 'email',
          pass: 'password'
      }
    });
    let mailDetails = {
      from: 'okormorupraisecoding@gmail.com',
      to: 'okormorupraisecoding@gmail.com',
      subject: 'New signup',
      text: "email"
    };
    mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails)
  }
  
  
  
  return (
    <div>
        <Wholesignupcontainer g={g}/>
    </div>
  )
}
export default page
```

other component

```
function Wholesignupcontainer(props) {
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    props.g()
  };

  return (
   
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Send Email</button>
    
  );
}

export default Wholesignupcontainer;
```

Comment: You can't send emails on the client. Don't try it. Just don't. Send the data to the server and let the server send the email.

Comment: but i want the email to be sent only when the user clicks the button . Is there any way i could do that?

Comment: Send a request back to the server, either by using fetch or just submitting an HTML form.

Comment: please is there any way i can contact u so we can talk more on the issue? pls

Comment: You first need to figure out the roles or the client and server. Do a bit of research, and you'll understand their responsibilities, and why and how to send an email from the server with a trigger on the client side.